# If DRAM access has to follow exact order?

Tags: memory-management, architecture

Consider a thread wants to access first DRAM bank-2,then bank-0 and at last bank-1. If all these 3 requests appear to the memory controller at the same time, is it possible for the controller to do the reordering (i.e first access bank-1, then bank-2 and finally bank-0) or memory controller has to follow the exact order requested by the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is reordering if it is allowed by architecure-defined [memory ordering rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering) and is implemented in memory controller. If it is not allowed by architecure ordering,  memory controller may execute accesses out-of-order, but **must emulate** correct ordering using some load/store buffers in internal SRAM.

The reordering between bank-2, bank-0, bank-1 is easier when there is only single thread in system (UP, not SMP). If there are two threads, such reordering may break ordering rule (for exapmle something like every thread sees results of memory access by other thread in the same order as they were issued).

Some exapmles:

Xilinx since Virtex-6 has memory controller with bank reordering: http://www.xilinx.com/txpatches/pub/documentation/misc/improving%20ddr%20sdram%20efficiency.pdf Improving DDR SDRAM Efficiency with a Reordering Controller 2009

> If the workload contains adjacent accesses to different row addresses on the
>   same bank (row-address conflict), followed by an access to a different bank, a
>   simple in-order memory controller will serialize all three accesses, incurring a substantial efficiency penalty due to the precharge-activate for the second access. In contrast, a reordering memory controller is able to send the activate for the first access and then the activate for the third access, overlapping these accesses and thereby improving efficiency

As they write, reordering can be very useful on "Alternating reads/writes", since modern DDR 2/3/4 has high speed only for burst requests, and there are commands for mode switching (read/write), executed at memory bank frequency (several bus clock cycles) - [tRTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory#Memory_timing), DDR1 has TRW=CL–WL+(BL/2)+2, and WTR (write to read) as WL–CL+BL/2+1.

Check also 2000 paper http://cva.stanford.edu/publications/2000/mas.pdf Rixner, Memory Access Scheduling,  ISCA-27